# ARM CMSIS DSP throughput for average of N float samples

Tags: arm, signal-processing, cmsis

I wrote a simple C-code to compute average of N `float`s that exist in an array. I got 10.5 ClockCyles per float as throughput for large N.

`arm_mean_f32()` is actually poorer in performance.

Isn't this too many CCs/float?

The 3 operations

1. load-from-memory
2. accumulation-of-loaded-values
3. increment of pointer

can happen in parallel.

Does ARM Cortex M4F do this?

The project was run on custom board with Freescale K24 processor having ARM Cortex M4F.

Comment: I guess your floating point divide take a lot of time. Try per-compute the reciprocal and multiply it with the sum, Should save some time.

Answer (score 1):

ARM implementation is very traditional you can check it on [Github](https://github.com/ARM-software/CMSIS_5/blob/develop/CMSIS/DSP/Source/StatisticsFunctions/arm_mean_f32.c) , they just do loop unrolling to reduce loop overhead then accumulate the sum of 4 samples each loop and finally divide the number of samples, i tried it with M4F and i got 5.3 cycles per float.

Here is the code i used

```c
#include "arm_math.h" 
#define MAX_BLOCKSIZE 32

float32_t src_buf_f32[MAX_BLOCKSIZE] =
{
  -0.4325648115282207,  -1.6655843782380970,  0.1253323064748307,
   0.2876764203585489,  -1.1464713506814637,  1.1909154656429988,
   1.1891642016521031,  -0.0376332765933176,  0.3272923614086541,
   0.1746391428209245,  -0.1867085776814394,  0.7257905482933027,
  -0.5883165430141887,   2.1831858181971011, -0.1363958830865957,
   0.1139313135208096,   1.0667682113591888,  0.0592814605236053,
  -0.0956484054836690,  -0.8323494636500225,  0.2944108163926404,
  -1.3361818579378040,   0.7143245518189522,  1.6235620644462707,
  -0.6917757017022868,   0.8579966728282626,  1.2540014216025324,
  -1.5937295764474768,  -1.4409644319010200,  0.5711476236581780,
  -0.3998855777153632,   0.6899973754643451
};
float32_t result_f32; 

int main(void)
{
 arm_mean_f32(src_buf_f32, MAX_BLOCKSIZE, &result_f32);
 return 0;
}
```

I think this is the best performance you can get with floating point, your poor performance can be due to that your are measuring the number of cycles incorrectly or your silicon. you can also try to increase compiler optimization.